# How can user.get_profile() return one dataset and user.account another?

Tags: django, user-profile

My setup looks roughly like this:

```
# account/models.py
Account(models.Model):
    """ The user profile """
    user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User", primary_key=True, related_name="account")
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=32, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ...
```

And I have a signal handler that looks like this:

```
def recalculate_credit(sender, instance=None, created=None, **kwargs):

    print(instance.user.account.activation_key)

    account = instance.user.get_profile()

    print(account.activation_key)

    account.calculate_balance()
    account.save()
```

I've added the print statements there to highlight the problem.  During my registration process, I set the `activation_key` property, save, and then this signal is fired later.  The first print statement returns that activation key, the second returns `''`.

How is this possible?  Am I missing something in how `.get_profile()` works?  The code above is actually removing the `activation_key` value from the user account.  Is there some lazy loading going on, or object caching that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Try printing `(instance.user.account.__class__, instance.user.account.id)` and `(instance.user.get_profile().__class__, instance.user.get_profile().id)`, just to make sure you're really getting what you expect and the two objects are identical.

Comment: (<class 'account.models.Account'>, 25) and (<class 'account.models.Account'>, 25L) Not exactly identical, but really close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, so what's going on here is that django doesn't re-load the `.account` attr or the value of `.get_profile()` from the DB every time, it'a cached after the first access. To fix, either get a totally fresh copy from the DB with `Account.objects.get(id=user.account_id)` when you need to guarantee that the object is fresh, or only access the related `Account` object through *either* the `.get_profile()` API or the `.account` related descriptor - not both. As long as you access the object in the same way that you did before calling `.save()` on it, you shouldn't have this issue.

Conceptually, the underlying issue is that Django doesn't do any identity mapping - `Foo.objects.get(id=1)`, run twice, will result in two separate `Foo` objects in memory. Their attributes won't be shared, and updating one won't change the other. It's more appropriate to consider them "snapshots" of what that model's DB row looked like when it was retrived from the DB. To find out what the DB value is *right now*, you have to run the query again.